# Pycharm type hints warning for classes instead of instances

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, static-methods, type-hinting, abstract-methods

I am trying to understand why pycharm warns me of wrong type when using an implementation of an abstract class with static method as parameter.

To demonstrate I will make a simple example. Let's say I have an abstract class with one method, a class that implements (inherits) this interface-like abstract class, and a method that gets the implementation it should use as parameter.

```
import abc


class GreetingMakerBase(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def make_greeting(self, name: str) -> str:
        """ Makes greeting string with name of person """


class HelloGreetingMaker(GreetingMakerBase):
    def make_greeting(self, name: str) -> str:
        return "Hello {}!".format(name)


def print_greeting(maker: GreetingMakerBase, name):
    print(maker.make_greeting(name))

hello_maker = HelloGreetingMaker()
print_greeting(hello_maker, "John")
```

Notice that in the type hinting of `print_greeting` I used `GreetingMakerBase`, and because `isinstance(hello_maker, GreetingMakerBase) is True` Pycharm is not complaining about it.

The problem is that I have many implementations of my class and dont want to make an instance of each, so I will make this `make_greeting` method static, like this:

```
class GreetingMakerBase(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def make_greeting(name: str) -> str:
        """ Makes greeting string with name of person """


class HelloGreetingMaker(GreetingMakerBase):
    @staticmethod
    def make_greeting(name: str) -> str:
        return "Hello {}!".format(name)


def print_greeting(maker: GreetingMakerBase, name):
    print(maker.make_greeting(name))


print_greeting(HelloGreetingMaker, "John")
```

This still works the same way, but apparently because the parameter in the function call is now the class name instead of an instance of it, Pycharm complains that:
`Expected type 'GreetingMakerBase', got 'Type[HelloGreetingMaker]' instead.`

Is there a way I can solve this warning without having to instantiate the `HelloGreetingMaker` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are doing `print_greeting(HelloGreetingMaker, "John")`, you are not trying to pass in an *instance* of HelloGreetingMaker. Rather, you're passing in the class itself.

The way we type this is by using `Type[T]`, which specifies you want the type of T, rather then an instance of T. So for example:

```py
from typing import Type
import abc

class GreetingMakerBase(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def make_greeting(name: str) -> str:
        """ Makes greeting string with name of person """


class HelloGreetingMaker(GreetingMakerBase):
    @staticmethod
    def make_greeting(name: str) -> str:
        return "Hello {}!".format(name)


def print_greeting(maker: Type[GreetingMakerBase], name):
    print(maker.make_greeting(name))


# Type checks!
print_greeting(HelloGreetingMaker, "John")
```

Note that `Type[HelloGreetingMaker]` is considered to be compatible with `Type[GreetingMakerBase]` -- `Type[T]` is covariant with respect to T.

The [Python docs on the typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) and the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects) have more details and examples if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You did not create an instance, and your type hints implies that the function only accepts instances (something of a type `GreetingMakerBase`, and not `GreetingMakerBase` itself or a subclass of it).

If you want to specify that only `GreetingMakerBase` itself is an acceptable argument, why have it as an argument at all? Just have the function call that class internally.

In any case, python 3.8 has some new typing improvements that can help you. You can specify a [literal type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
from typing import Literal
def print_greeting(maker: Literal[GreetingMakerBase], name):
    print(maker.make_greeting(name))
```

If you need to support this type-hint in other (earlier than 3.8) python versions, you will have to install the [typing extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/):

```
pip install typing-extensions
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I do not want the function to only accept ```GreetingMakerBase``` itself, I want it to only accept subclasses of it (like implementations of an interface). In my real project there are many subclasses, I have just used one as this is a simplified example.

Comment: Literal type hints won't work here -- they can only accept literal values such as strings, ints, and bools. And also enum values, which aren't really literals, but whatever. [The PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/) goes into more details about this. You're looking for typing.Type instead.